# Flutter table_calendar Custom Header

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a custom header using the [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) package.
So far I have been able to get the month using `_calendarController.focusedDay.month` and creating a list of months. However I am unable to build the left and right arrows for the header. How do I set a focusedDay with the current year and date but the previous month? And is there an easier way to do this?